# Read does not receive EOF even though I close all my pipes C

Tags: c, linux, fork

Trying to give a Minimal Viable Example of the problem. Basically the method `send_chars_to_reducers` sends a character to the proper `reducer_pipe`. The `fork_reducers` function remains in its while loop until it receives EOF but it never does even though I close all reducer pipes in `send_chars_to_reducers`. I know it doesnt exit the while loop because it never prints exiting reducers.

### C Code

```
void send_chars_to_reducers(char * line) {
    printf("SEND_CHARS_TO_REDUCERS read: %s\n\n", line);
    int i;
    int ob_size = 1;
    int wlen = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        if (line[i] >= ALPHA_OFFSET && line[i] < ALPHA_OFFSET + LETTERS) {
            int pipe_num = line[i] - ALPHA_OFFSET;
            printf("SENDING %c TO REDUCER PIPE %d\n", line[i], pipe_num);
            wlen = print_if_err(write(reducer_pipes[pipe_num][PIPE_WRITE_END], &line[i], ob_size), "write");
            printf("WROTE %s to REDUCER %d\n", line[i], i);
        }
    }
    close_reducer_pipes();
}

void close_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        close(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
        close(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END]);
    }
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            int j;
            for (j=0; j < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; j++) {
                close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                if (j != i) {
                    close(mapper_pipes[j][PIPE_READ_END]);
                }
            }
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            send_chars_to_reducers(ibuf);
            close_reducer_pipes(); 
            //printf("forked mapper%d read: %s\n\n", i, ibuf);
            close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END]);
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {
    printf("HELLLOOOO FROM REDUCER\n"); 
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {
            while (1) {
                rlen = print_if_err(read(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1), "read");
                if (rlen > 0) {
                   printf("REDUCER #%d, read %s\n", i, ibuf);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }       
            printf("exiting reducer\n");
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

### Entire C Code

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024
#define ALPHA_OFFSET 97
#define LETTERS 26

const int NUM_OF_MAPPERS = 4;
const int NUM_OF_REDUCERS = 26;

const int PIPE_READ_END = 0;
const int PIPE_WRITE_END = 1;
const int PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;

int mapper_pipes[4][2];
int reducer_pipes[26][2];
int letter_count[26];

void init_letter_count(void) {
    int i;
    for (i =0; i < 26; i++) {
        letter_count[i] = 0;
    }
}

void pipe_wrapper(int pipefd[]) {
    int ret = pipe(pipefd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("Error. Failed when trying to create pipes.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void create_mapper_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(mapper_pipes[i]);
    }
}

void create_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pipe_wrapper(reducer_pipes[i]);
    }
}

// Prints an error msg and exits if one occurs. Else, returns the system call value.
int print_if_err(int syscall_val, const char* syscall_name) {
    if (syscall_val < 0) {
        perror(syscall_name);
        exit(errno);
    } else {
        //No syscall error we can return
        return syscall_val;
    }
}

void send_chars_to_reducers(char * line) {
    printf("SEND_CHARS_TO_REDUCERS read: %s\n\n", line);
    int i;
    int ob_size = 1;
    int wlen = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++) {
        if (line[i] >= ALPHA_OFFSET && line[i] < ALPHA_OFFSET + LETTERS) {
            int pipe_num = line[i] - ALPHA_OFFSET;
            printf("SENDING %c TO REDUCER PIPE %d\n", line[i], pipe_num);
            wlen = print_if_err(write(reducer_pipes[pipe_num][PIPE_WRITE_END], &line[i], ob_size), "write");
            printf("WROTE %c to REDUCER %d\n", line[i], pipe_num);
        }
    }
    printf("END OF SEND CHAR FOR LOOP");
    close_reducer_pipes(); 
}

void close_reducer_pipes(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        print_if_err(close(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]), "close");
        print_if_err(close(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END]), "close");
    }
}

void fork_mappers(void) {


    /* Constants useful to all children */
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_OF_MAPPERS; i++) {
        pid_t mapper_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (mapper_pid == 0) {
            int j;
            for (j=0; j < NUM_OF_MAPPERS; j++) {
                close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                if (j != i) {
                    close(mapper_pipes[j][PIPE_READ_END]);
                }
            }
            rlen = print_if_err(read(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1000), "read");
            send_chars_to_reducers(ibuf);
            //printf("forked mapper%d read: %s\n\n", i, ibuf);
            close(mapper_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END]);
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void fork_reducers(void) {
    printf("HELLLOOOO FROM REDUCER\n"); 
    char ibuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE]; // input pipe buffer
    int rlen = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_REDUCERS; i++) {
        pid_t reducer_pid = print_if_err(fork(), "fork");
        if (reducer_pid == 0) {
            while (1) {
                rlen = print_if_err(read(reducer_pipes[i][PIPE_READ_END], ibuf, 1), "read");
                printf("RLEN = %d\n", rlen);
                if (rlen > 0) {
                   int letter_count_i = ibuf[0] - ALPHA_OFFSET;
                   printf("REDUCER #%d, read %s, letter_count_i = %d\n", i, ibuf, letter_count_i);
                   letter_count[letter_count_i]++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }       
            printf("REDUCER EXITING\n");
            _exit(0);
        }
    }
}

void send_lines_to_mappers(void) {
    int wlen = 0;
    char obuf[PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int ob_size;
    int count = 0;

    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE]; // a buffer for each line of the file
    FILE *input_file = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    // read the input file line by line
    while(fgets(buff, BUFFER_SIZE, input_file) > 0) {
        //printf("send_lines_to_mappers read: %s\n\n", buff);
        ob_size = sizeof buff;
        switch(count) {
            case 0 :
                write(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                close(mapper_pipes[0][PIPE_READ_END]);
                break;
            case 1 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                close(mapper_pipes[1][PIPE_READ_END]);
                break;
            case 2 :
                write(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                close(mapper_pipes[2][PIPE_READ_END]);
                break;
            case 3 : 
                write(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END], buff, ob_size);
                close(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_WRITE_END]);
                close(mapper_pipes[3][PIPE_READ_END]);
                break;
            default :
                printf("you did something wrong in send_lines_to_mappers loop");
        }
        count++;
    }
    fclose(input_file);
}

int main(void) {
    init_letter_count();
    // Setup the mapper pipes
    create_mapper_pipes();
    create_reducer_pipes();
    fork_reducers();
    fork_mappers();
    send_lines_to_mappers();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any EOF except the commenter above...

Comment: You never check for eof in the code that you've posted.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer By EOF I mean `if rlen = 0`

Comment: @EOF I added the entire file for compiling

Comment: What value does `rlen` have when you read after the FD is closed?

Comment: TL;DR. And C does not support _methods_, only _functions_

Comment: One common cause of this sort of problem is that after you fork, there are two copies of the write end of your pipe, so even if you close one of them, the other one still exists and, as long as it does, you'll never get EOF on the read end.  IIRC, the fix tends to be to make sure to close the unnecessary writing end after you fork and before you exec.

Comment: @SteveSummit this sounds like the right answer but arent a closing the pipes in `close_reducer_pipes`? Or do I need to close from the parent also?

Comment: close the end of the pipe that the current process (parent process/child process) is not going to use, before performing any I/O on the pipe.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted (after edit) code causes the compiler to output lots of warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  (I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` ) )

Comment: the use, when declaring a function, of `...(void)` is not correct.  Only include the `void` when writing the prototype for the function.  in the actual declaration use `()` .  there are unused variables: `rlen`, `obuf`, `wlen`.  the returned value from `fgets()` has type `char*` not `int` so comparisons should be to `NULL`, not `0`

Comment: the posted code contains many 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. Numbers like; 26, 2, 4,1000, 97. 1024.   Suggest using `#define` statements or an `enum` to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.  Note: `const` value do not work well in C for defining values as the result takes extra CPU cycles to fetch from readonly memory

Comment: While a 'programmer' could let the OS handle cleanup (close files/pipes, free memory, etc) when the program exits, the result is very sloppy program AND will not work everywhere, especially in embedded applications running on the 'bare metal'.   Rather than getting into such bad habits. strongly suggest closing pipes/files and freeing allocated memory within the application.

Comment: regarding the function: `print_if_err()`,  The first parameter is expected to be a entry number from the table of system calls,  however, what is actually being passed is a pointer to function.  so this probably will not work as expected.  On a 64 bit architecture, a function pointer is 64 bits, but an `int` is only 32 bits.  The result will not be what you want.

Comment: it is a bad programming practice to #include header files those contents are not being used.   the header file `sys/wait.h` is such an example

Comment: after calling `perror()`, the value of `errno` is undefined (could be anything)  so do not  do this: `perror(syscall_name); exit(errno);`   rather do: `perror(syscall_name); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 0):

When you create a pipe, there are two ends ("file descriptors"), the reading end and the writing end.

When you fork(), the child process inherits ALL the open file descriptors, including both ends of ANY open pipe.

So, if you want:

```
[child1] >===pipe1===> [parent] >===pipe2===> [child2]
```

for example, then you have a several file descriptors to close.

- In child1, you need to close the READ end of pipe1 AND BOTH ends of
  pipe2.
- In child2, you need to close the WRITE end of pipe2 and BOTH ends of
  pipe1.
- In the parent, after you are done forking, you need to close the
  WRITE end of pipe1 and the READ end of pipe2.

As you have lots of pipes, you will have even more closing to do.

If you are not sure you have everything closed, the program `lsof` ("list open file-descriptors") can be helpful.